# CSS media queries and div background color

Tags: html, css

I feel embarrassed asking this question, but I've tried all kinds of ideas and googled quite a bit.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-full"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-full {width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#000;}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .image-full {background-color:#f00;}
    body {background-color:#f00;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .image-full {background-color:#0f0;}
    body {background-color:#0f0;}
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .image-full {background-color:#00f;}
    body {background-color:#00f;}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .image-full {background-color:#ff0;}
    body {background-color:#ff0;}
}
```

I simply want the div to change background color like the body background is.

What am I missing?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bn5bh6xj/

**EDIT:**

Both solutions below work.

My problem was that I had a hidden character ( Â ) earlier in my CSS code. I sometimes get them when I code on my mac (in both Sublime Text and Coda, on several different macs and OS X versions). I've spent hours trying to find the reason for them, but no luck. They always appear in PHP before opening a bracket block, like this:

```
if (hello > 1)Â {

}
```

They are only visible if I change from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1.

Comment: I reproduced the demo in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jaheso/2/edit) and it worked for me (As I expected). That's weird that I couldn't get it to work on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bn5bh6xj/5/). Actually both selectors have the same specificity value, hence the later should override the earlier.

Comment: you should add your edit as your own answer and accept that answer, accepting an incorrect answer is not the way good for community, or at least the answer should be corrected based on your solution.

Comment: @KingKing you would be right if my initial code actually worked. It didn't, I needed one of the fixes. Anyways, thanks for staying on top of things :)

Comment: @Mattis not sure which one you need here but actually all the solutions below are wrong, what you found is exactly the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `background-color` declaration from the top. It is overriding your `background-color` declarations in the media queries.

Comment: Beat me to it, here is a fiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/bn5bh6xj/4/

Comment: I swear to some holy entity I had tried both that and !important. I also had tried putting the "main" class declaration at the bottom. Well, thank you :)

Comment: Guess what, it still didn't work. But I found the error. You are both right - but the actual fix was that I had a hidden character ( Â ) earlier in the CSS file. I sometimes get them when I code in OS X. When I removed it both your fixes worked.

Comment: so this is not the actual reason, the style in @media should be capable to override the style before, no need to remove the `background-color` outside.

Comment: I've run into a similar issue before , and the @media was not capable of overriding it.

Comment: @Youngin you can just need to try it yourself, here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/3dpdfeht/ it works just fine. The OP's problem is in fact very very hard to understand at first, but luckily he found his very hidden issue.

Comment: Interestingly it appears that you can override background but not background-color. See here http://jsfiddle.net/kp9nh48e/

Answer (score 3):

Add a `!important` after the background color:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .image-full {
        background-color:#f00 !important;
    }
    body {
        background-color:#f00;
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bn5bh6xj/2/)

Comment: I did try that already, does not work for me. Perhaps a browser inconsistency.

Comment: Read comment on other answer, your solution were ok. Thanks!

Comment: awesome, glad you fixed it